# Convert trdx file (Telerik Reporting) to use in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, telerik, visual-studio-2012, telerik-reporting

We recently started using Telerik Reporting.  Some users use the Telerik Report Designer, while I use Visual Studio 2012.  Is there a way to import their trdx reports into my Visual Studio class library?

Comment: You could probably include the file itself, but in regards to using them in you VS 2012 IDE, most likely not,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not supported and in all honesty would be unnatural and tedious task for Telerik to do if they were to do it (create .net class from xml file). I believe they did it one way(VS -> xml) as in most cases devs would create a base/template report that regular users can modify.